# Programmatically unhooking an event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, textchanged

I want to conditionally unhook an event handler. Is this the right way to do it:

```
tb.TextChanged -= textBoxIntName_TextChanged;
```

?

This seems to be sensible, as hooking it up required:

```
tb.TextChanged += textBoxIntName_TextChanged;
```

...but it also seems that what corresponds to the "Delphi way" makes as much or more sense (but alas, it does not compile):

```
tb.TextChanged = nil;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign events - only attach (+=) and remove (-=) operations are available for clients.

Read more about events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx).

Also C# specification [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Since += and -= are the only operations that are permitted on an event
>   outside the type that declares the event, external code can add and
>   remove handlers for an event, but cannot in any other way obtain or
>   modify the underlying list of event handlers.

Comment: We must be talking semantics here, because from my perspective my assignation of events is working (using +=).

Comment: @ClayShannon nope, actually this adds another event handler to underlying list of event handlers (in your case this list is stored in TextBox). Events in .Net is something like Observer pattern. Subject (TextBox) holds collection of Observers (event handlers) and notifies them when event occurs. You can only add observer to collection, or remove it from collection. But you has no access to collection - its internal part of Subject.

Comment: I realize the Observer pattern, or publish and subscribe, is at work here, but it's still the case that using += is doing what I expect/want it to do. If it's not literally being assigend, I really don't care, because it acts as if it is.